# A notion dual to a product type having a given type

Tags: category-theory, haskell

Consider this class:

```
class Has record part where
  extract :: record -> part
  update :: (part -> part) -> record -> record
```

It captures the notion of some product type `record` having a field of the type `part` which can be `extract`ed from the `record`, or the functions on which can be used to `update` the whole record (in a lens-ish manner).

What happens if we turn the arrows? Following the types and noting that a sum type is dual to a product type, and a "factor" in a product type is analogous to an option in a sum type, we get

```
class CoHas sum option where
  coextract :: option -> sum
  coupdate :: (sum -> sum) -> option -> option
```

Firstly, is this line of reasoning correct at all?

If it is, what is the meaning of `coextract` and `coupdate`? Obviously, `coextract` produces the `sum` out of one of its `option`s, so it might as well be called `inject` or something similar.

`coupdate` is more interesting. My intuition is that, given a function `f` that updates a sum type, it gives us a function that can be used to update one of its options. But, obviously, not every `f` is fit for this! Consider

```
badF :: Either Int Char -> Either Int Char
badF (Left n) = n
badF (Right _) = Left 0
```

then `coupdate badF` does not make sense where `coupdate` is taken from `CoHas (Either Int Char) Char`. One requirement seems to be that the function passed to `coupdate` must not change the tags of the sum type.

So here's the second question: what's the dual of this requirement in the `Has`/`update` case?

My intuition is that it's not as straightforward because `Has` *produces* a function and `CoHas` *consumes* a function. Things get more symmetric if we consider the rules for the type classes, something along the lines of

1. `update f . update g = update (f . g)`
2. `update id = id`
3. `extract . update f = f . extract`

Now we can actually talk about bad instances of `Has` producing `update` functions breaking these rules. But even with this additional constraint, I'm not sure I follow what the laws for the functions that `coupdate` accepts should be and how one could derive them from such duality-based reasoning.

Comment: Where is the category theory in this? Have you tried setting up any commutative diagrams to see what arrows it makes sense to reverse?

Comment: I'd say the main CT part is resorting to duality. In particular, $\mathbf{Hask}$ is the category (with the well-known caveats). I couldn't come up with a non-trivial diagram except for the diagram for the laws I mentioned, but it seems a bit artificial.

Comment: When you want to dualize a categorical construction, say, monoid objects, you first write down the equational laws as commutative diagrams, then flip the arrows *in the diagrams*. This tells you what arrows you need to flip in the type signatures (protip: not necessarily all of them).

Comment: What if I didn't have `update`/`coupdate` in this particular case? I cannot think about any laws wrt `extract` alone, so how would I obtain `coextract`?